# How to read from pipeline command line by line in C++?

Tags: c++, shell, stdin

I have a cpp program called example.cpp. In this program I want to read from stdin line by line and save each line in one string. However it is not from keyword or file. The input is from command line:

```
CC example.cpp -o ALO
last -n 10 | ./ALO
```

I have tried following which are couple of ways but neither work for this:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}


return 0;
```

or

```
char name[256];
while (cin.getline (name,256))
{
    cout << "Got " << name << endl;
}
```

or

```
string name;
while (getline(cin, name))
{
    cout << "Got " << name << endl;
}
```

Update:

The output I get at the moment is

```
Got sshd
Got 192.131.251.2
Got Thu
Got Mar
Got 27
Got 18:16
Got -
Got 18:17
Got (00:00)
Got dwm914
Got sshd
Got mega-pc21.cs.uow
Got Thu
Got Mar
Got 27
Got 18:16
Got -
Got 18:17
Got (00:01)
Got tb713
Got pts/71
Got 192.131.251.2
Got Thu
Got Mar
Got 27
Got 18:15
Got -
Got 18:16
Got (00:01)
Got tb713
Got sshd
Got 192.131.251.2
Got Thu
Got Mar
Got 27
Got 18:15
Got -
Got 18:16
Got (00:01)
```

desired output:

```
bkg988    sshd         139.218.157.100  Thu Mar 27 20:00 - 20:00  (00:00)
sh615     sshd         cpe-121-216-173- Thu Mar 27 19:57 - 19:59  (00:01)
sh615     sshd         cpe-121-216-173- Thu Mar 27 19:57 - 19:59  (00:01)
```

Comment: stdin works the same whether it's reading from a file, terminal, or pipe. I think the last version should work.

Comment: I have written the example of the output

Comment: The first and third version are equivalent (except for the `"Got"` output), and they should work. Can you send the output to a file instead and verify that it doesn't actually contain those newlines?

Comment: That looks like what you would get if you did `cin >> name` instead of `getline`.

Comment: I sent it to a text file and it is line by line :(

Comment: To clarify, you want multiple input lines concatenated into a single string that ends with a `)` character.  Is this correct?